# Online Status Report Tool?

Tags: report

The development team I work on needs a way to store and compile status reports. They should also be exportable to a searchable format.

Currently our reports are just emailed up the chain (which also means we can export them to our personal accounts for updating our resumes later based on our experience). However, this requires manual compilation to get 4 people's responses under one question. (Think Q1: R1, R2, R3, R4... Q2: R1, R2, etc...)

Does anybody know of a free tool that we could use?

Comment: very broad.. a shared excel sheet, a networked access database, a custom web+database solution, a custom winforms+database app, salesforce.com, etc. could all match.

Comment: It is broad. I like the simple/pretty tools (typically seem Rails-based) so if I could find one like that then that could work.

Otherwise I might be tempted to write up a custom solution and perhaps put it on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reportify](http://reportify.com.au/) addresses this need, especially the part about automating collation of team member responses.

**Disclosure**: I am the founder of Reportify.

Answer (score 2):

We are using http://standup.report (which is free), it allows us to do our daily stand up meetings (our offshore team also use it). The interface is cool, very easy-to-use.

Answer (score 1):

I am admittedly biased as a founder, but I think we have a very robust offering for you at http://www.statuspath.com

We make it easy to roll reports up the chain, provide a consolidated view across many reporters, reference activity data while composing reports, and much more.

Comment: I've been checking out this app from this post, and the UI is incredibly responsive and very straight forward. A few things could likely use some more clarity into what they are without having to hover over them. Having to hover to get additional information makes it inaccessible for touch.

Answer (score 0):

We searched for something to do remote stand up meetings and now we are using [Teamreporter](http://www.teamreporterapp.com) at our team.